# Will collecting iOS advertisingIdentifier ever lead to crash?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, idfa

Our app collects idfa through this [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier).

It's a simple computed property:

```
var idfa: String {
    return ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
}
```

But seems like it has a very low chance of crashing, based on our production record, it crashes 1 out of a million runs.

The stack trace is:

```
- 0   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000184c34728 0x184c1b000 + 104232
- XXXApp 0x000000010bd42d70 AdsDataCollector.idfa.getter + 156118384 (AdsDataCollector.swift:0)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What kind of crash?

Comment: Did you asked on Apple developer forum ?

Comment: Does this radar match your issue? If so this might be a known bug. http://www.openradar.me/46397907

Comment: @meaning-matters hmm, do you mean the stack trace is a bit short?

Comment: @PtitXav that's a good idea, let me give it a try

Comment: @Shawn the radar links to the github issue: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/issues/4404 . My stack trace doesn't show "UUID._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(_:)", but the comment "From what I understand, there is some case where advertisingIdentifer can be nil and this make Swift crash." might be the case for me.